# Magento not updating Sitemap automatically

Tags: magento, cron, sitemap

My Sitemap is not generating automatically. I have enabled Google Sitemap in System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Google Sitemap -> Generation Setting
and entered all the values.

But sitemap is not updating in Catalog -> Google Sitemap.

I have also tried to truncate cron_schedule table but no luck with that.

Comment: This may not be enough detail for a reader familiar with Magento to understand what the issue is. Can you isolate the code that generates the sitemap and run that separately? Are there any system or PHP logs you can check to see if there is anything relevant there?

Comment: I have just a small question - How to generate Sitemap with Cron? Is that possible in Magento?

Comment: I can see [several answers here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+generate+Magento+Sitemap+with+Cron), any good?